# Multi-dimensional tensor dot product in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor, dot-product

I have two tensors of shapes (8, 1, 128) as follows.

```
q_s.shape
Out[161]: torch.Size([8, 1, 128])

p_s.shape
Out[162]: torch.Size([8, 1, 128])
```

Above two tensors represent a batch of eight 128 dimensional vectors. I want the dot product of batch `q_s` with batch `p_s`. How can I do this? I tried to use `torch.tensordot` function as follows. It works as expected as well. But it also does the extra work, which I don't want it to do. See the following example.

```
dt = torch.tensordot(q_s, p_s, dims=([1,2], [1,2]))

dt
Out[176]: 
tensor([[0.9051, 0.9156, 0.7834, 0.8726, 0.8581, 0.7858, 0.7881, 0.8063],
        [1.0235, 1.5533, 1.2155, 1.2048, 1.3963, 1.1310, 1.1724, 1.0639],
        [0.8762, 1.3490, 1.2923, 1.0926, 1.4703, 0.9566, 0.9658, 0.8558],
        [0.8136, 1.0611, 0.9131, 1.1636, 1.0969, 0.9443, 0.9587, 0.8521],
        [0.6104, 0.9369, 0.9576, 0.8773, 1.3042, 0.7900, 0.8378, 0.6136],
        [0.8623, 0.9678, 0.8163, 0.9727, 1.1161, 1.6464, 0.9765, 0.7441],
        [0.6911, 0.8392, 0.6931, 0.7325, 0.8239, 0.7757, 1.0456, 0.6657],
        [0.8493, 0.8174, 0.8041, 0.9013, 0.8003, 0.7451, 0.7408, 1.1771]],
       grad_fn=<AsStridedBackward>)

dt.shape
Out[177]: torch.Size([8, 8])
```

As we can see, this produces the tensor of size (8,8) with the dot products I want lying on the diagonal. Is there any different way to obtain a smaller required tensor of shape (8,1), which just contains the elements lying on the diagonal in above result. **To be more clear, the elements lying on the diagonal are the correct required dot products we want as a dot product of two batches. Element at index [0][0] is dot product of q_s[0] and p_s[0]. Element at index [1][1] is dot product of q_s[1] and p_s[1] and so on.**

Is there a better way to obtain the desired dot product in pytorch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it directly:

```
a = torch.rand(8, 1, 128)
b = torch.rand(8, 1, 128)

torch.sum(a * b, dim=(1, 2))
# tensor([29.6896, 30.4994, 32.9577, 30.2220, 33.9913, 35.1095, 32.3631, 30.9153])    

torch.diag(torch.tensordot(a, b, dim=([1,2], [1,2])))
# tensor([29.6896, 30.4994, 32.9577, 30.2220, 33.9913, 35.1095, 32.3631, 30.9153])
```

If you set `axis=2` in the sum you will get a tensor with shape `(8, 1)`.